# While operator undefined

Tags: javascript

I want to make a small calculator in javascript.
I got the html code looking like this (for all the numbers)

```
<button type="button" onclick="calcNum(1)">1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="operator('+')">+</button>

 var myNumbers = [];
```

The calcnumber function like this:

```
function calcNum(i) {       
    myNumbers.push(i);
    var x = document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = myNumbers.join("");       

}
```

and the operator function like this:

```
function operator(op) {
    var operator = op;
    var y = document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = operator;
}
```

My goal is to make it like this:
If I press 1,2,3 I want the screen element to display "123" (which it does) if I press "+" I want "+" to be displayed (which it does) however when the operator is pressed, and then a new number is pressed I want it to start on a new number, right now if I press "123" and then + and then "456" I get:

123456, instead I want it to display "456", hence starting on a new number. Hope it's all clear.

I figured I could add this to the calcNum function:

```
while(op == "undefined") {
   keep pushing numbers // but this does not work
}
```

In the end I want to construct a calc function which takes all the numbers up to a operator is pressed as the FIRST number, then concatanate with the operator and the second number and adding them together.

Comment: Any answer to this will have to address your underlying design - ergo you currently only have one array (`myNumbers`) that you're pushing digits in to.  You're going to need some sort of stack of things to keep track of what's going on.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend not using the function's name as a local variable within it. It works (unless you need to recurse), but it's really confusing.

Comment: Right, why can't I just add all the numbers up to an operator is pressed at myNumbers[0] and all the numbers after the operator at mynumbers[1] and then add them togehter? Am I missing anything essential?

Comment: because `myNumbers` is `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`.  Did the user enter `123` and `456` or `12` and `3456` etc.  You need to define a different way to hold the information.  Perhaps when the operator is pushed you save the current contents of `myNumbers` to another variable and clear it ready for more input, but that's not going to scale if you want to support more than one operator being used in each calculation etc.

Comment: Right, would you suggest me using two different arrays? myFirstNumbers & mySecondNumbers instead? Or do you suggest anything else? Appreciate your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several issues in your code but I don't know if it is due to the fact that you didn't copy all your code in your question.

First, the `operator` function is incorrect : you give a local variable the samename than the function. If you want the function return a value, use the `return`keyword.

> I figured I could add this to the calcNum function:
>
> while(op == "undefined") {    keep pushing numbers // but this does
>   not work }

Where is `op`defined? The only `op` I see is a local variable of the `operator`function. It will always be `undefined` in `calcNum`.

Note also that if you want to test if a variable is undefined, you should not test

```
if (myVar == "undefined")
```

but

```
if(typeof myVar == "undefined")
```

Finally I'd change your code this way (should be tested though):

```
var currentNumber= "";
var entries = []
function calcNum(i) {       
    currentNumber +=i;
    document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = currentNumber;       
}


function operator(op) {
    var y = document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = op;
    //Note that you could already process the entered operations as if you clicked on '=' 
    //and display the result instead of displaying the operation...
    if(currentNumber != ""){//there must be a number entered before you click on an operator
        entries .push(currentNumber);
        entries .push(op);
        currentNumber= "";

    }
}
```

And you still need of course to implement what you do when you click on `=`...

Comment: Thank you. My calculation function will not work however. I've designed in a poor manner perhaps, but as I'm new to this it is hard to cope with the logic behind it. I've tried the addition function as down below. However it only concatanes the string, rather than adding them up to a number so the output might be something like:

4 +  6 = 46 instead of 10

function calc() {
 if (entries[1] == "+") {
  var result = entries[0] + currentNumber;
  document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = result;

Comment: did you have any ideas about this? Forgot to tag you. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Change your functions like this

```
var numbers = "";
function calcNum(i) {       
myNumbers.push(i);
numbers +=i;
var x = document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = numbers;       

}
```

and

```
function operator(op) {
var operator = op;
var y = document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = operator;
myNumbers.push(op);
numbers = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare above:

```
var leftOperand = null;
var lastOperator = null;
```

In calcNum:

```
if(lastOperator !== null) {
  document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = '';
  leftOperand = myNumbers.join('');
  myNumbers = [];
  lastOperator = null;
}
// rest of the function
```

In operator:

```
lastOperator = op;
// rest of the function
```